# Replace field data with virtual table data

Tags: virtual

I have a table with a state column

```
Area    Loc State
ABC      1    X 
ABC      2    Y 
ABC      3    X 
ABC      4    Y 
ABC      5    Z
```

I would like to name put a name instead of the State but the names are no in any table

```
State   Name 
X       Empty 
Y       Full 
Z       Partial
```

to get the following result

```
Area    Loc State
ABC      1  Empty
ABC      2  Full 
ABC      3  Empty
ABC      4  Full 
ABC      5  Partial
```

Comment: Is there a specific language you want this in? Either way, we won't do it for you, you should include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: to use in MS SQL Server

Comment: This is my basic Query   
SELECT DISTINCT Area, Zone, State 
FROM TABLE  
WHERE State in ('X', 'Y', 'Z')  
Group By Area, Zone, State